# SQL check if date value has 5 days straight

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a date column contains date value, I want to see if all the date values contains 5 day straight for example

```
2019-03-15
...
2021-06-01 
2021-06-02
2021-06-03
2021-06-04
2021-06-05
....
2021-07-01
```

In this case returns true

The only catch is that the syntax must work with SQL Server 2008 R2 version

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: We are a startup and we cant afford the latest version.

Comment: SQL Server Express 2019 is free with a 10GB database limit, and Web Edition isn't too badly priced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract an enumerated value and that is constant for adjacent dates.  Then aggregate and count.

So, to get all sequences of 5 or greater:

```
select min(date), max(date), count(*)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by dateadd(day, - seqnum, date)
having count(*) >= 5;
```

If you want to return a `'true'`/`'false'` value:

```
select (case when exists (select min(date), max(date), count(*)
                          from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
                                from t
                               ) t
                          group by dateadd(day, - seqnum, date)
                          having count(*) >= 5
                         )
              then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as flag
```